# Get all checked values in recursively generated checkboxes

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a recursive checkboxes with the following code

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

let lastId = 0;
let lastKey = 0;

const Leaf = (props) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <Form.Check
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={props.checked}
        onChange={(e) => props.valueChanged(e.target.checked)}
        id={++lastId}
        label={props.name}
      />
    </li>
  );
};

const Node = (props) => {
  const nodetype = typeof props.node === "object" ? true : false;
  const nodename = nodetype ? Object.keys(props.node)[0]: props.node;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(props.checked ? props.selected.includes(nodename): false);
  const children = props.node[nodename];
  
  function link(a){
    props.update(a, nodename)
    setChecked(a)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Leaf name={nodename} checked={checked} valueChanged={a => link(a)} />
      {nodetype & checked ?
      <ul>{
        children.map((n) =>
        <Node node={n} 
          selected={props.selected} 
          key={++lastKey} 
          checked={checked}
          update={(a, c) => props.update(a, c)}
          />)
      }</ul> 
      : ""}
    </>
  )
};


const breakdown = [
  {Animal : [ {Canine : ["Dog", "Wolf", "Jacket"]}, {Feline : ["Cat", "Tiger", "Lion"]}]}
]
const TagApp = () => {  
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(["Animal", "Canine"]);

  function update(a, c){
    a ? setSelected([...selected, c]) : setSelected(selected.filter(x => x !== c))
    console.log(selected)
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {breakdown.map((n) => (
        <Node node={n} 
          selected={selected} 
          key={++lastKey} 
          checked={true} 
          update={(a, c) => update(a, c) } />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TagApp;
```

The selected checkboxes are `Animal` and `Canine`. When `Animal` is unchecked, I want `Canine` to go too. Or, in case of an event, I want **my state** to **store only the values** whose checkboxes are **checked**.

I tried using `useEffect` when the parent checkbox is unchecked but it does not give the children value.

Any hint or help is appreciated. Here is the implementation of the code on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-snow-bgmf9c?file=/src/tagtree.jsx).